# How to take 2 letters from input (ignoring white chars and can't use arrays)

Tags: java

The exercise looks simple get, get the first 2 letters from the input no matter the position on the string, it also asks to stop the program if the user doesn't put two letters (Uper or Lower case ... users choice).

I tried some stuff but the program never works right, I tried to search up a solution but couldn't find anything help full to java...

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    System.out.print ("2 Letras? ");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    char L1 = s.next().charAt(0);
    int l1 = L1;
    char L2 = s.next().charAt(1);
    int l2 = L2;
    char M1, M2;

    if (l1<63 || l2<63 || l1>90 || l2>90 || l1<95 || l2<95 || l1>122 || l2>122)
        return;
    else{
        if (l1>96) 
            M1 = (char)(l1 + 32);
        else 
            M1 = (char)(l1);

        if (l2>96) 
            M2 = (char)(l2 + 32);   
        else 
            M2 = (char)(l2);

    }

    System.out.println("" + M1 + M2);
```

Is expected to get the 2 letters from the user in Upercase in the end...

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.next().trim().substring(0, 2).toUpperCase()`

- Having a `scanner`, you take the whole input line by `scanner.next()`, - the result is a user input string. The subsequent `next()` call will wait for the next input line, wich does not look algoritmically correct.
- To cut heading and tailing whitespace chars use `String::trim`
- To cut first two symbols from the user input, use `String::substring` method
- better way to get your char uppercased is `String::toUpperCase`.

So, the result of this snippet is first to chars of a user input, turned to upper case

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: thanks but im also limited on what i can use on the strings from all of those only to upper case is alowed